# Is Azure Databricks available within Azure GovCloud?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-gov

**Context:** We're looking at using Azure Databricks within AzureGovernment.

**Question:** Is this service supported in AzureGovernment? Its very difficult to find information on this topic. I found this [blog](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/558487-azure-government/suggestions/34277734-azure-databricks-in-azure-gov#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D), which says Databricks has planned preview in AzureGov within Q1 of 2020...but Q1 2020 ends in a few days...so if anyone can point me in the right direction for more info please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [`Azure Products By Region`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?regions=usgov-non-regional,us-dod-central,us-dod-east,usgov-arizona,usgov-iowa,usgov-texas,usgov-virginia&products=databricks) page, the service is expected to be **available in preview during Q2 2020** in US Gov Arizona and Virginia regions as of writing this answer.

[image]

You can always check for availability of Azure Services by region here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/.